# how to transcribe speech into text with google cloud speech to text api for real time transcription without using library

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-platform, google-chrome-extension, google-speech-to-text-api, transcription

I found transcripted text after clicked on stop button but it is not transcripting in real time and showing an error :- Error: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '0')

I tried this code for transcribing speech into text in real time and also passed a combined audio stream together of system and microphone audio.

```
let desktopMediaStream = null;
let microphoneStream = null;
let isRecording = false;
let combinedMediaRecorder = null;
let combinedStream = null; 
let recordedChunks = [];
let recognition=null;

window.addEventListener('message', function (e) {
  let closeMes = e.data;
  if (closeMes === 'start') {
    startRecording();
  } else if (closeMes === 'stop') {
    stopRecording();
  }
});

async function startRecording() {
  try {
    desktopMediaStream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getDisplayMedia({ preferCurrentTab: true, audio: true, video: true });
    microphoneStream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ audio: true, video: true }); // Updated options: audio: true, video: false

    const audioContext = new AudioContext();
    const microphoneSource = audioContext.createMediaStreamSource(microphoneStream);

    if (desktopMediaStream.getAudioTracks().length > 0) {
      const destination = audioContext.createMediaStreamDestination();
      const desktopAudioSource = audioContext.createMediaStreamSource(desktopMediaStream);
      desktopAudioSource.connect(destination);
      microphoneSource.connect(destination);

      combinedStream = destination.stream;
      combinedMediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder(combinedStream);
    ///////////////////////////
      // const audioChunk = mediaRecorder.getAudioChunk();
      // transcribeAudio(audioChunk);

      combinedMediaRecorder.ondataavailable = (event) => {
        recordedChunks.push(event.data);
        // audioChunk = btoa(event.data);
        // const blob = new Blob([event.data], { type: "audio/mp3" });
        transcribeAudio(event.data);
      };

      // setInterval(transcribeAudio, 500);
      var interval = setInterval(transcribeAudio, 500);


      // combinedMediaRecorder.addEventListener("dataavailable", (event) => {
      //   recordedChunks.push(event.data);
      //   transcribeAudio(event.data);
      // });


      combinedMediaRecorder.addEventListener('stop', () => {
        const combinedAudioBlob = new Blob(recordedChunks, { type: "audio/wav" });

        // Create a download link
        const downloadLink = document.createElement("a");
        downloadLink.href = URL.createObjectURL(combinedAudioBlob);
        downloadLink.download = "combined_audio.wav";
        
        // Append the download link to the document body
        document.body.appendChild(downloadLink);

        // Programmatically trigger the click event
        downloadLink.click();

        // Remove the download link from the document body
        document.body.removeChild(downloadLink);

        recordedChunks = [];
        clearInterval(interval);

        stopRecording();
      });

       combinedMediaRecorder.start();
       isRecording = true;

    } else {
      console.error('No audio track found in the desktopMediaStream.');
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error starting recording:', error);
  }
}


function stopRecording() {
  console.log("Clicked on stopRecording button");
  if (isRecording) {
    if (desktopMediaStream) {
      desktopMediaStream.getTracks().forEach((track) => track.stop());
    }
    if (microphoneStream) {
      microphoneStream.getTracks().forEach((track) => track.stop());
    }
    if (combinedStream) {
      combinedStream.getTracks().forEach((track) => track.stop());
    }
    isRecording = false;
  }
}
```

Here I am calling API through transcribeAudio function.

```
function transcribeAudio(audioData) {
  const blob = new Blob([audioData], { type: "audio/wav" });
  const reader = new FileReader();
  reader.onload = function (event) {
    const audioBytes = event.target.result.split(',')[1]; // Extract base64 encoded audio bytes
    const requestBody = {
      audio: {
        content: audioBytes,
      },
      config: {
        encoding: 'MP3',
        sampleRateHertz: 48000,
        languageCode: 'en-US',
        enableAutomaticPunctuation: true,
        diarizationConfig: {
          enableSpeakerDiarization: true,
          minSpeakerCount: 2, // Set the minimum number of expected speakers
        },
      },
    };

    // Send the API request
    fetch(`${apiUrl}?key=${apiKey}`, {
      method: 'POST',
      body: JSON.stringify(requestBody),
    })
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(data => {
        // Process the API response
        console.log('Transcripted data:', data);

        // Access the transcripted text
        const transcriptedText = data.results[0].alternatives[0].transcript;
        console.log('Transcripted text:', transcriptedText);

        // Access speaker diarization results
        const words = data.results[0].alternatives[0].words;
        const speakerDiarization = extractSpeakerDiarization(words);
        console.log('Speaker diarization:', speakerDiarization);
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.error('Error:', error);
      });
  };
  reader.onerror = function (event) {
    console.error('File reading error:', event.target.error);
  };

  reader.readAsDataURL(blob);
}

// Helper function to extract speaker diarization information from words array
function extractSpeakerDiarization(words) {
  let speakerDiarization = {};
  for (const word of words) {
    const speakerTag = word.speakerTag;
    if (!speakerDiarization[speakerTag]) {
      speakerDiarization[speakerTag] = [];
    }
    speakerDiarization[speakerTag].push(word.word);
  }
  return speakerDiarization;
}
```

Comment: have you managed to do this?